# take a fragment of HTML code, apply a unique id and place on page

Tags: jquery, radio-button, css-selectors

I want to take a fragment of HTML code containing some radio buttons,
apply a unique id and label identifier, then place them on the page.
...As usual I am having trouble with the jQuery selectors

** Update - I revised question with working example ***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js'></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div id="placeholderA">content goes here.</div>
        <div id="placeholderB">content goes here.</div>
        <div id="placeholderD">content goes here.</div>
        <div id="placeholderC">content goes here.</div>
        <div id="placeholderE">content goes here.</div>
        <div id="placeholderF">content goes here.</div>
        <div id="placeholderG">content goes here.</div>
    </div>

<a href="#" data-icon="check" id="preShowHTML" data-iconpos="none">Show HTML</a>
<pre><div id="HTMLOut"></div></pre>
</div>      

</body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    // buttons have to be added to multiple groups on the page
    var groups2 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'] ;

    for (var groupLetter in groups2){
            // clone fragment of html
            myClone = $(dataType);  

            // create a unique id name for first radio box
            // (we do this because jquery mobile will fail if duplicate id's or label for's exist...)
            name = "preConfigRadio-" + groups2[groupLetter] + "1";  
            // apply id name to first radio box 
            myClone.find('input[name="myRB"]:eq(0)').attr("id", name);
            myClone.find('label[name="myRB"]:eq(0)').attr("for", name);

            // apply id name to second radio box 
            name = "preConfigRadio-" + groups2[groupLetter] + "2";              
            myClone.find('input[name="myRB"]:eq(1)').attr("id", name);
            myClone.find('label[name="myRB"]:eq(1)').attr("for", name);

            // apply id name to third radio box 
            name = "preConfigRadio-" + groups2[groupLetter] + "3";              
            myClone.find('input[name="myRB"]:eq(2)').attr("id", name);
            myClone.find('label[name="myRB"]:eq(2)').attr("for", name);

            // then append
            myClone.appendTo("#placeholder"+groups2[groupLetter]).trigger('create');            
    }

    /* Toggle Show/Hide HTML */
    $('#preShowHTML').click(function() {    
         $("#HTMLOut").text($("body").html());
         $("#HTMLOut").toggle();
        return false;
    });             

});     

    dataType =  "<fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal'>\n\
        <input type='radio' name='myRB' id='' checked='checked' value='C' /><label  name='myRB' for=''>A</label>\n\
        <input type='radio' name='myRB' id='' value='T' /><label name='myRB' for=''>B</label>\n\
        <input type='radio' name='myRB' id='' value='P' /><label name='myRB' for=''>C</label>\n\
    </fieldset>";


</script>
```

Comment: why's there an `\n\ ` in `dataType`?

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin: That way you can use inline newlines in a string.

Comment: makes it easier to read when you view source

Comment: You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is a little incorrect.

```
myClone.('input[@name="myRB"]')[0].attr("id", name);
```

1. You're trying to call a function with no name which isn't possible
2. (You can remove the `@`)
3. (You can use `:eq(n)` instead of `[n]`)

So you might want this instead:

```
myClone.find('input[name="myRB"]:eq(0)').attr("id", name);
```

etc.

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: had some issues with "label for" as well.